# Identify when the surfaceview is fully transparent

Tags: android, surfaceview, transparent

I'm writing a scratch card like app, and I use a SurfaceView for that.
I fill it with some kind of color and I draw some Path on it with PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR PorterDuffXfermode. I have to identify when the user fully scratched it (the SurfaceView's canvas is fully transparent). Can anybody give me some advice, how to identify it?

I tried it with saving the coordinates of the paths, but because of the drawing stroke width I can't calculate the covered area well.

I tried to get a Bitmap from the SurfaceView's getDrawingCache method and iterate on its pixels and use the getPixel method. It doesn't work and i think it would be not an efficient way to examine the canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the canvas will not be large or scalable to an arbitrary size I think looping over the pixels would be effective.

Given a canvas of large or arbitrary size I would create an array representation of the canvas and mark pixels as you go, keeping a count of how many the user has hit at least once. Then test that number against a threshold value that determines how much of the ticket must be scratched for it to be considered "scratched off". Incoming pseudo-code

```
const int count = size_x * size_y; // pixel count
const int threshhold = 0.8 * count // user must hit 80% of the pixels to uncover
const int finger_radius = 2; // the radias of our finger in pixels
int scratched_pixels = 0;
bit [size_x][size_y] pixels_hit; // array of pixels all initialized to 0

void OnMouseDown(int pos_x, int pos_y)
{
    // calculates the mouse position in the canvas
    int canvas_pos_x, canvas_pos_y = MousePosToCanvasPos(pos_x, pos_y);
    for(int x = canvas_pos_x - finger_rad; x < canvas_pos_x + brush_rad; ++x)
    {
        for(int y = canvas_pos_y - finger_rad; y < canvas_pos_y + brush_rad; ++y)
        {
            int dist_x = x - canvas_pos_x;
            int dist_y = y - canvas_pos_y;
            if((dist_x * dist_x + dist_y * dist_y) <= brush_rad * brush_rad
                && pixels_hit[x][y] == 0)
            {
                ++scratched_pixels;
                pixels_hit[x][y] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

bool IsScratched()
{
    if(scratched_pixels > threshhold)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I can track the finger position, but it does not give a correct result at the end, because I draw the paths on the canvas with some stroke width.

Comment: In that case represent the finger as a circle and find all the pixels that circle intersects. Then test them all as opposed to the single one show. I can provide some pseudo code if needed.

Comment: I'am done with that, the solution was similar to what you said in the last comment. If you write it as an answer I will accept it.